# Which library defines these symbols: nmgetch kbd_again initkbd resetkbd

Tags: linker, cygwin, symbols

I'm trying to compile version 7.16 of [**sc**](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/apps/financial/spreadsheet/), the ncurses spreadsheet calculator, for cygwin. Compilation fails due to undefined references: **nmgetch**, **kbd_again**, **initkbd**, and **resetkbd**. Google search, and grepping a Ubuntu machine with apt-get-installed **sc**, has got me nowhere. Does anyone recognise these names?

Answer (score 1):

in fact I was able to compile and get arrow keys working,
the right CFLASG to put in the Makefile is :

```
CFLAGS=-DSYSV3 -I/usr/include/ncurses/
```

You don't need to change the `SIMPLE=` variable (you can leave it as it is in Makefile)

If you leave the `-O2` and `-pipe` flags your SC won't be working properly (it won't process editing options - syntax error)

Answer (score 0):

These functions are defined within **sc**. They are required to build **sc**, but undefined by default. If the C preprocessor macro, `SIMPLE`, is defined, a "simple" implementation of these functions is enabled. So call make as follows, to allow it to find cygwin's curses.h:

```
make CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/ncurses SIMPLE=-DSIMPLE
```

But now the arrow keys don't move the cursor.